# How to get a macro do an action for each query record/row?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm building a room booking system in access, and I need some help with a macro regarding a query.

This is the form people will see when they come to book rooms:

﻿[image: FORM]

This works fine.

What I've done is create a query that returns, depending on the day, what times a particular room is scheduled for.

[image: QUERY]

This particular query is for Room 111 today. So here, it shows that today, Room 111 is unavailable for Periods 3,4 and 6.

I need to write a macro that looks at each of these lines and blanks out the relevant text box control on the form.

So it should end up looking like this:

[image: EXAMPLE]

I don't know if this is possible using Macros, or if I will need to use Visual Basic. I just need to get the macro/code to say:

"FOR Each Row, IF 111ScheduleCheck.TimeSlot="Period 1", THEN FORMAT 111_P1 TO Background=Black"

"FOR Each Row, IF 111ScheduleCheck.TimeSlot="Period 2", THEN FORMAT 111_P2 TO Background=Black"

etc etc

I've tried this however it doesn't work:

[image: MACRO]

When I run it, I just get this error:
[image: ERROR]

Can somebody help me do this?

Thanks,

Rowan :)

Comment: Have you tried [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Highlight-data-on-forms-by-using-conditional-formatting-44fe5b63-b6fa-48ea-966e-b5e54eb072b0)?

Comment: I suggest you forget about macros and use VBA. -- Is your form a continuous form or a single form? If continuous, this won't be easy.

Comment: There may be a crosstab possibility with conditional formatting as @ThomasInzina suggests. Please tell us how form is bounded or not. Aside - you can use left/right arrow embedded images in command buttons (see Format tab of Property Sheet) instead of the character *-->*

Comment: The form is a single form and all textboxes are unbound.

Comment: Can we see the query's SQL as there is a chance to return all room's availability on form?

Comment: @Parfait Yes of course, I have also included the table for Room 111's schedule. If you think this can be done differently, please let me know!

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwyJgRETuZ2dWnpvWURBaFZJbTA&usp=sharing

Comment: The [TempVars]![SelectDate] is the temporary variable for the date selected on the form (with the arrow buttons)

Answer (score 1):

Consider bounding the form to the pivoted query below on a continuous/multiple item form where textboxes will serve as the Period fields with a Room field. Also, there might be room to normalize tables where all Rooms will use one Schedule table, thereby avoiding below union query.

```sql
SELECT dT.Room, dT.Day, 
       Max(IIF(dT.[Time Slot] = 'Period 1', 'Yes', NULL)) AS [Period 1],
       Max(IIF(dT.[Time Slot] = 'Period 2', 'Yes', NULL)) AS [Period 2],
       Max(IIF(dT.[Time Slot] = 'Period 3', 'Yes', NULL)) AS [Period 3],
       Max(IIF(dT.[Time Slot] = 'Period 4', 'Yes', NULL)) AS [Period 4],
       Max(IIF(dT.[Time Slot] = 'Period 5', 'Yes', NULL)) AS [Period 5],
       Max(IIF(dT.[Time Slot] = 'Period 6', 'Yes', NULL)) AS [Period 6]
FROM
    (SELECT 'Room 111' As Room, [Day], [Time Slot] FROM Schedule111
     UNION SELECT 'Room 121' As Room, [Day], [Time Slot] FROM Schedule121
     UNION SELECT 'Room 122' As Room, [Day], [Time Slot] FROM Schedule122
     UNION SELECT 'Room 125' As Room, [Day], [Time Slot] FROM Schedule125) AS dT
GROUP BY dT.Room, dT.Day
```

And then [conditionally format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-6ba9e9fa-4347-4183-b335-44e43b05e22f) each of the six Period textboxes with background coloring:

```
[Field Value Is] equal to "Yes".
```

Finally, filter the form by the day value of the current page using form's OnCurrent trigger event. Be sure the date header control is a true Date formatted textbox:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Day]='" _
      & WeekdayName(WeekDay(Forms!YourForm!YourDateControl,2)) &"'")
```

Comment: Sorry for being a bit simple, but I'm new to VBA :P. Would I create a module for this or edit the code of the query?

Comment: First, create a stored query with the SQL script. Then, create a multiple item form bouned to this new query with seven textboxes for Room and six Periods. Day field will be used in filter. Next, use conditional formatting on Period textboxes (under Home an of Ribbon). Finally place the apply filter in the `OnCurrent()` VBA subroutine of the form (or use embedded macro).

Comment: When creating a query with the code above, Access returns with a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error. I created the table 'dT' where the Room is also a field so that, like you say, all the schedules can be put into one table.